# Using orWhere in a multiple where query builder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to select from database pads with 4 conditions, with 1 condition have to use "or". I wrote this query builder, it works. But I want to know if i can use a shorter query. Like use 3 conditions in a "where" brackets, and 1 in "orWhere" bracket. This is my query:

```
$pads = DB::table('pads')
    ->join('languages', 'pads.language_id', '=', 'languages.id')
    ->select('pads.id', 'pads.title', 'pads.status', 'pads.people', 'pads.created_at', 'languages.name as language')
    ->where([
        ['pads.user_id', Auth::user()->id],
        ['pads.title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"],
        ['pads.status', $request->status],
        ['pads.language_id', $request->lg_id]
    ])
    ->orWhere([
        ['pads.user_id', Auth::user()->id],
        ['pads.people', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%"],
        ['pads.status', $request->status],
        ['pads.language_id', $request->lg_id]
    ])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group your conditions within the `OR` within a `orWhere()` with a function as the argument.

```
->where([
        ['pads.user_id', Auth::user()->id],
        ['pads.status', $request->status],
        ['pads.language_id', $request->lg_id]
    ])
->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('pads.title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")
          ->orWhere('pads.people', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%");
})
```

This will produce a query similar to

```sql
WHERE pads.user_id = ?
  AND pads.status = ? 
  AND pads.language_id = ?
  AND (
       pads.title LIKE ?
       OR pads.people LIKE ?
   )
```

Comment: Thank you. I know your idea. But we need to change that "->orWhere(function($query) use ($request)" in your code to "->where"